How to find how many sessions had specific action from JSON column in SQL
I have a table with 2 columns, session_id and json_column. Each row is at session level and json_column has all the event name <> event time stamp a user took during that session. event names are not repeated so it will have one event time stamp for each event name. For example lets assume the table has only 2 rows and json_column value will look like this for those rows,
row 1: {
"app_close": 104,
"video_playback": 110,
"video_start": 541
"video_end": 500
}
row 2: {
"video_start": 541
"did_request_playback": 110,
"video_end": 539
}
The expected output is,
Event Name : # of sessions -- column name
video_start: 2
app_close: 1
video_playback: 1 
did_request_playback: 1
video_end: 2

Can some help me with SQL query for this please?

That's not really the proper way to organize this.  You should have three columns: session_id, action, timestamp.  Now you can do aggregate queries.

action column here will have multiple actions, this will only increase the columns and I guess I will have to manually add those which is not scalable approach? Unless you have better way to handle. would appreciate your help

No, I mean exactly those three columns.  Your data above would have 7 rows.  Then SELECT COUNT(*),action FROM table GROUP BY action; gets you your data.

sorry I don't get it. I get the aggregate query part but I'm stuck at the inner query you were referring to. could you share full query if you don't mind

maybe this fiddle is a good place to start https://dbfiddle.uk/SJG3aoTU

@BartMcEndree Thanks. The challenge I have is, it has 100+ different event name so I can't type those as columns

You can parse you JSON (assuming you have correct one and not the data in the question), cast it to map, unnest and then perform groping by event name:
-- sample data
WITH dataset(session_id, json_column ) AS (
   values ('row 1', '{ "app_close": 104, "video_playback": 110, "video_start": 541, "video_end": 500 }'),
        ('row 2', '{ "video_start": 541, "did_request_playback": 110, "video_end": 539 }')
)

-- query
select k event_name, count(distinct session_id) sessions
from (select session_id, k, v
    from dataset
    , unnest(cast(json_parse(json_column) as map(varchar, json))) as t(k,v))
group by k;

Output:



event_name
sessions




video_end
2


video_start
2


video_playback
1


app_close
1


did_request_playback
1



P.S.
As far as I remember Presto and Trino have differences when unnesting maps, the query was written for Trino and might need small tweaks for Presto.

this worked , thanks!
